# When I keep refreshing my angularJS page, the content sometimes shows up, sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a page running angularJS. Sometimes, when I open the document, the data that needs to appear only sometimes shows up. When I keep trying to refresh the page, it's pretty much random: sometimes the content appears, sometimes it doesn't.

The section of the code that runs this looks like this:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="(observer,hosts2) in bugDuration">
                        {{observer}}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="(host, bugs2) in hosts2"> {{host}} 
                                <div ng-repeat="(bug, duration) in bugs2">
                                    {{bug}} for {{duration}} seconds.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

As you can see, it is using ng-repeat, and my best guess is that when this code is running, the ng-repeat objects, such as `bugDuration` are empty, so none of it runs.

My script that initializes all of these variables is located after, in my document. Is there something I should do in the controller or whatever so the variables can be refreshed and the content can be shown everytime?

---

Edit

---

Here is the code where bugDuration is initialized:

```
 bugDuration = {};
                    bugTracker = {};

                    $.getJSON('../java_output/bugs.json', function (data) {
                        for ( var observer in data ) {
                            bugDuration[observer] = {};
                            for (var host in data[observer]) {
                                bugDuration[observer][host] = {};
                                for (var bug in data[observer][host]) {
                                    bugDuration[observer][host][bug] = data[observer][host][bug].duration;    
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        console.log (bugDuration);
                    });


                    $.getJSON('../java_output/bug_summary.json', function (data) {
                        var numObservers = data.numObservers;
                        delete data['numObservers'];
                        JSONbugsList = data;
                        var bugTracker = {};
                        for (var observer = 1; observer <= numObservers; observer++) {
                            observers.push(observer);
                            observerKeys = Object.keys(data);
                            // observerKeys.splice(observerKeys.indexOf('numObservers'));
                            for (var host in data["observer" + observer]) {
                                if (hosts.indexOf(host) == -1) {
                                    hosts.push(host);
                                }
                                hostKeys = Object.keys(data["observer" + observer]);
                                for (var bug in data["observer" + observer][host]) {
                                    if (bugs.indexOf(bug) == -1) {
                                        bugs.push(bug);  
                                    }
                                    for (var i in  data["observer" + observer][host][bug]) { 
                                        bugTracker[bug] = true;
                                        var dateVar = data["observer" + observer][host][bug][i];
                                        var intoList = {"observer":observer, "host":host, "bug":bug, "start":(new Date(1000*dateVar.start)), "end":(dateVar.end==null?' the end.':(new Date(1000*dateVar.end)))} 
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }



                       // Removed unimportant stuff here//



                        $scope.$apply();
                        $scope.hostsS = hosts;
                        $scope.bugsS = bugs;
                        $scope.observersS = observers;
                        $scope.JSONbugsList = JSONbugsList;
                        $scope.hostKeys = hostKeys;
                        $scope.observerKeys = observerKeys; 
                        $scope.start = 'start';
                        $scope.end = 'end';
                        $scope.bugDuration = bugDuration;
                        $scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Could you show the code where the `bugDuration` variable is initialized?

Comment: @runTarm I've updated my original post with the code. Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner using AngularJS, so I may have made some novice errors.

Comment: Have you looked in the browser's [JavaScript Console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) to see if there are error messages on the times that it doesn't load?  If there are error messages, and you still don't understand why it doesn't work, then post the messages here.

Comment: please use $http, using $.ajax, the changes are happening outside of angular world, which i guess is cause of the problem

Comment: @HarishR, how and where should I use $http? I am not very familiar with AngularJS, sorry.

And yes I have checked it many times, and there are no errors.

Comment: read this article [angular-ajax](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/ajax.html)

Comment: @HarishR Thanks, I see. Where exactly should I be implementing this? Like what should the $http replace?

Comment: it should replace $.ajax, you dont or rather you shouldnt use $.ajax in angularjs world, though you can fix it using Sscope.$apply, that not right way to do things in angular

Comment: @HarishR I don't believe I've used $.ajax anywhere here.

Comment: sorry i meant $.getJSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem among others is that `$scope.$apply()` needs to happen after the data gets set on the `$scope`. Since $.getJSON is asynchronous, by the time the callback gets triggered, the `$scope.$apply()` lines at the bottom will have already been fired.

```
$.getJSON('../java_output/bug_summary.json', function (data) {
  /*do stuff outside of angular context when the ASYNC callback fires*/
  $scope.stuff = data;
  /*then call $scope.$apply()*/
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: I apologize if I misunderstood your answer, but isn't that what I did (except I put a `$scope.$apply()` before and after instead of just after. I've tried putting it only after, and the same thing was happening.

Comment: Do you see how function(data){} is a parameter of the $.getJSON() function? That means it is a callback so javascript will execute the code on the bottom and then wait to execute that function until the bug_summary.json comes back. So, if you don't have the $apply INSIDE that callback function, it won't work. This is how javascript and ASYNC ajax calls work.